# How to export obj/fbx/json file for three.js with the second uv(lightmap)?

Tags: json, three.js, fbx

The second layer UV is used to map lightmap onto models in the scene. When the work with a second uv is done in 3D Max, can we export all these information to a obj/fbx/json file that can be loaded directly by three.js?

Here is an example provided by threejs.org https://threejs.org/examples/?q=lightmap#webgl_materials_lightmap
when looking into the file "obj/lightmap/lightmap.js", we can see somes properties such as "mapLight".

So my question is how this json file is created? Is there any exporters that can export the mapLight property? I have tried export the second uv from 3d max using obj and fbx format, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export a json file with the second uv (lightmap) for three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819806/how-to-export-a-json-file-with-the-second-uv-lightmap-for-three-js)

Comment: No need to create duplicate questions, update / change your first one if you need to

Comment: Sorry, another post has been deleted!